# Extract 12-bit integer from 2 byte big endian (motorola) bytearray

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, micropython

I am trying to extract an integer which occupies up to 12 bits in a 2 byte (16 bit) message, which is in big-endian format. I have done some research already and expect that I will have to use bit_manipulation (bit shifting) to achieve this, but I am unsure how this can be applied to big-endian format.

A couple of answers on here used the python 'Numpy' package, but I don't have access to that on Micropython. I do have access to the 'ustruct' module, which I use to unpack certain other parts of the message, but it only seems to apply to 8 bit, 16bit and 32bit messages.

So far the only thing I have come up with is:

```
int12 = (byte1 << 4) + (byte2)
expected_value = int.from_bytes(int12)
```

but this isn't giving me the number's I am expecting. For example `0x02,0x15` should present decimal 533 .
Where am I going wrong?

I'm new to bit manipulation and extracting data from bytes so any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: What is the type of `byte1(2)`? Note: there is a `byteorder` parameter in the `from_bytes` method. You can pass either 'little' or 'big' to it. So maybe something like `expected_value = int.from_bytes(byte1+byte2, byteorder='big') << 4` should work.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] to show us. What is `byte1` and `byte2` and how were they initialized? Also what result do you actually get? Please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your feedback, I tried to give an example below the code but it probably isn't enough, will do better in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
import struct

val, _ = struct.unpack( '!h', b'23' )
val = (val >> 4) & 0xFFF
```

gives:

```
>>> hex(val)
'0x333'
```

However, you should check what 12 bits out of 16 are occupied. My previous code assumes that those are the upper 3 nibbles. If the number occupies lower 3 nibbles, you don't need any shifts, just the mask with `0xFFF`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this works great, I was just missing the &0xFFF Mask!